# Main text among numbered list

Tags: numbering

I would like to create the numbered list with alignment, but without horizontal shift relative to the main text like this:
[image]

Numbering can even be manual.

Comment: This looks like a job for the `resume` option in `enumitem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\hangindent` primitive register to indent the numbered paragraphs from their second line.

```
\parindent=0pt
\def\num #1.{\par
   \hangindent=1.2em \hskip1.2em \llap{#1. }\ignorespaces
}

The main text the main text the main text the main text the main text the
main text the main text the main text the main text.

\num 1. text text  text text text text text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text.

\num 2. text text text.

The main text the main text the main text the main text the main text the
main text the main text the main text the main text.

\num 3. text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\num 4. text text text.

\bye
```